# Does OpenTelemetry support UWP

Tags: open-telemetry

I tried to integrate OpenTelemetry .NET instrumentation with UWP and it consistently threw an exception in Sdk.CreateTracerProviderBuilder().  The exact same sample code works fine in a non UWP app.  The error is:

```
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'OpenTelemetry.Resources.ResourceBuilder' threw an exception.'

Inner Exception
PlatformNotSupportedException: Retrieving information about local processes is not supported on this platform.
```

Could someone confirm that OpenTelemetry does not support UWP?  Thanks.

Comment: Based solely on the error message, I guess it doesn't support it. Tablet programs are terribly limited in what they can do, and the library seems to be enumerating processes, one of the restricted actions.

Comment: Thanks for the response.